# Split Bootstrap row on page resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize

I am trying to split a row I have into two rows when the page is resized to a much smaller width.

Right now my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- header -->

    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center top"> Text text <small> more text!</small> </h1>
    </div>
...
```

Ideally, I want to split up the `<small>` section and make it go under the rest of the `<h1>` when the page-width is made smaller.

Trying to do things along the lines of:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><h1> Text text</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><h1> <small>more text!</small></h1></div>
</div>
```

isn't giving the the effect I desire (it places a visual 'split' in-between the text but I want them to have a white background that uniformly covers them both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just display the small text as block?

```css
small {
display: block;  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center top"> Text text <small> more text!</small> </h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: You then need to change this to display: inline; with a media query

Comment: Thanks, so I have it set to inline in the regular CSS, and in a media query I set it to block. Works like a charm!